# Eclipse shortcut for Compare With Head Revision

Tags: eclipse, git

I want to have a keyboard shortcut for comparing the current open buffer with the HEAD version of that file. This is available in the context menu by clicking *Compare With/Head Revision*.

I tried to add a key binding in Preferences/General/Keys, but the key binding is ignored. I can set (and use) shortcuts for *Compare with other resource* and *Compare with previous version*, but the most useful one, *Compare with HEAD Revision* doesn't work. I couldn't find any difference between the ones that work and the ones that don't.

I am using Eclipse Helios (3.6.2).

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/764263/ <- looks like we are not only ones

Comment: I am surprised there aren't more people complaining. Seems such a useful and obvious shortcut!

Comment: Try to customize your perspective (right click on Eclipse toolbar) and add commands you like their shortcut work to your toolbar. I managed my SVN commands work this way.

Comment: @Mohsen, I'd want a key shortcut, not a toolbar button. But that would alleviate the problem, I agree.

Comment: This is a workaround to have keyboard shortcuts work. I didn't mean that you should use toolbar buttons. This way shortkeys should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after upgrading to EGit 2.0. I am now using Indigo (Eclipse 3.7.2).

I can set (and use) shortcuts to `Compare with HEAD` and `Show Annotations (blame)`, both of which didn't work before.

Comment: Does this solution still work? I don't see Compare with HEAD option in perspective customize dialog.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is actually what [Mohsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141438/mohsen) suggested: 
Window dropdown menu > Customize Perspective > Command Groups Availability and there check the Git box.

This enables the relevant shortcut keys for this perspective.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. As I said, it is *specifically* the `Compare with HEAD revision` that doesn't work. I can see the shortcuts, and `Compare with previous revision` works fine. Puzzled.

Comment: I was unaware of "Command Groups," let alone that they had to be enabled on a per-Perspective basis. They are similar to the "Category" listed in the key-binding editor, but as the OP finds, not the same: some commands in a "Category" are not in the corresponding "Command Group". A good change to the key-binding UI would be a hint that commands are not be available in a perspective unless enabled, and a link to the Customize Perspective dialog. Comments there should also change, as it discusses menu-items and toolbar-items, but not that the selection affects key-bindings as well.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Eclipse Window->Preferences
     General->Keys
         Select the Compare command and add bindings for it.

Comment: hmm... i am using STS. The above menu path has options to provide binding for almost all the commands. there is also the scope specifier so things like only do this action when i am in windows or editting java file etc. have you tried that?
my point was around having that binding available.

Comment: Quoting from the original question: "  tried to add a key binding in Preferences/General/Keys, but the key binding is ignored. I can set (and use) shortcuts for Compare with other resource and Compare with previous version, but the most useful one, Compare with HEAD Revision doesn't work. I couldn't find any difference between the ones that work and the ones that don't."